# Is it possible to acquire a lock while modifying a child & parent entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, locking

**My scenario:**
I am having a Parent and children entity. I want to read a child along with its parent, update it and save it back. I want the whole operation to happen with a lock.

**Current flow of execution:**

1. Get PARENT and CHILD Entity
2. Convert Entity to Domain objects (Following DDD design)
3. Update parent and child
4. Convert the CHILD Domain to CHILD Entity
5. Save the CHILD Entity. (Parent gets auto-saved as child has a ManyToOne relationship with parent object)

To **get** parent entity a findbyId method in ParentRepositoy is called and to **get** child method a FindById method in ChildrenRepository is called.

To **save** child and parent, saveAll method in childrenRepository is called. (Parent gets auto-saved through ManyToOne relationship)

I want here a Persistent_write lock, which should cover from read to write. But I am not sure which object to lock or which repository method to lock.

Can anyone help me out here, or elaborate if I misunderstood anything here.

Comment: Include some code snippet what you have done so far, can elaborate your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared the pessimistic_write lock in the **parent's repo.findby** method. As I only want the parent row to be locked and its working.

Code:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    List<...> findWithLockById(...);
```

Comment: Please add these code in your question. Not in the answer section. Or if you solve your problem with that code, then it could be ok.

Comment: that is the answer code